# Google My Business API - How to get reviews list from a location in Google My Business API

Tags: google-my-business-api

whasup?
I´m developing a widget like "Google Reviews for WP" to a customer of mine, to show on his site the list of google my business reviews of his places.
I´ve read all confuse documentation of Google Cloud and Google my Business API
and found this URI that they say is to be used to get my goals,
GET [https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/{parent=accounts/*/locations/*}/reviews](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/%7Bparent=accounts/*/locations/*%7D/reviews) or this one
POST [https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations:batchGetReviews](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/locations:batchGetReviews)
but I caný identify where I can find {accountId} or {parent=accounts/*/locations/*}.
I´ve followed all steps to create API Keys, ou OAuth2.0 credentials, but, i´ve got unauthorized response from servers when i try to use that URI on Postman to check if i´ve got the correct JSON answer... by other way, when i got the right URI, I receive 200 status, but unauthorized msg..
May someone, please help me?
I can´t use the WordPress plugins..
Thanks to whom help me...
Sorry by the "cracked english!"
Hugs to all!

Comment: Do you have access to the GMB API (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71489050/3062971 )?

Comment: Thanks for help. The P.O. requested the access to GMB API. We are waiting the answer from Google. Meanwhile we are researching the many ways to get our goals. By the way, we are following the links you send to us. Thanks for that again. It gaves me the lightway...

Comment: if you did  not solve your problem yet write here, I try my best to help.

Comment: Hi @shilamosammami, thanks for your time... I aprecciate that.
I´m waiting the answer from GMB Support team, giving the permission to GMB API access. Meanwhile i´m researching how to implement the solution.
if you have any ideas or ready code to use, i´ll be eternally grateful... i´m thinking use JS and fetch API at a first glance, and after that, refactoring the code to Angular.
Best regards

Comment: Hey guys, whassup?
well, i´m not solved this issue yet.
But, i´ve seen the things clearly now.

Comment: The reviews from GMB are private and need authorization level to be shown. But i just wanna to list the reviews on the website of the owner of the google my business account, without the visitors have to be looged in their google accounts just to see the list.
If anyone can help we apprecciate that
Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need direct API access (unless you only want the top 5 reviews) - you can use a widget offered on many sites free like reviewsmaker.com or elfsight.com